# Zenfone 5 t00j charging, but not recognized by computer

Tags: usb, asus-zenfone-5

I have bought a second hand t00j however it seems that when i connect it to the computer via usb, it is not listed anywhere, but it is still charging. I tried different USB ports. I have tried with one windows and one linux computer. The phone is in MTP mode, I have the latest intel drivers. It is not showing up in the devices tab on windows. I tried enabling usb debugging. Nothing is listed when i run "adb devices". I opened the phone to make sure the connector ribbons between the usb board, the sim card and the mombo are connected properly. Please help.

Comment: i also tried different usb ports, different computers and different operating systems (linux and windows)

Comment: so finally try different cables, too. use linux `lsusb`, make sure to enable MTP mode each time again once phone is plugged. if still no connection, replace jack

Comment: tried different cables too, have not tried lsusb, will try it now. The water damage marker was red inside the phone, so hardware damage is completely possible here.

Comment: lsusb shows nothing. Most likely a hardware failure then?

Comment: my j5 xnlte works perfectly well with all the devices mentioned above.